# Alpha zero output neuron configuration

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

How does is the output neuron of alpha zero configured, the actor head specifically, since the possible actions or move to play are actually infinite u cant have infinite output neurons with each representing the moves to make right?

Comment: The number of actions is not infinite.

Answer (score 0):

What you called "actor head" is defined as "policy" in AlphaZero. Basically it outputs a probability distribution over all possible actions you can make. For example, in TicTacToe you would need 9 values, one for each possible square you could place an X or a O into. You should also consider that AlphaZero was conceived for acting in discrete action spaces, where the actions or move to play are almost always finite. Continuous action spaces could probably be solved using this same method, but you would need to be a bit clever about the way you output your policy values, because, as you said, they might be infinite (an interval for example).